# Should we always unset a class as soon as possible if we want to use complex code in __destruct?

Tags: php, class, destructor, unset

I have the following problem. I'm using a class and  I want to do some 'event saving (and logging)' in the __destructor method, i need to be sure that my database class is still active, and even that my memcache class is still active.

I noticed that the destructor method can be called way too late. (database class no longer active, memcache class no longer active)

A workaround i have found is...

```
$forum = new Forum_class();
$forum->output();
unset($forum) <-- unset it
```

Is this a good practice? Or should i just skip using the destructor method to do stuff that relies on other classes being active... (available database class, available memcache class...)

I most likely shouldn't unset my database and memcache class as soon as possible  but for the other classes, should you unset them as soon as possible. (when they are not needed on the page anymore) Or only if you want to use the __destructor function?

Or am i doing something horrible wrong? It just seems weird to always have to make sure you unset a class. If i forget it once, my __destructor method can produce errors...

**Edit**: i think i stumbled upon this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39381. My database class and memcache class use globals...

Comment: You might want to look into [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function)

Comment: The more I read there the more i think that I just shouldn't rely on the __destructor method to do complex stuff... 

I can't just register my __destruct method as a shutdown function or it would be called twice. What would you register there? And what would it solve?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. But...

The destructor MIGHT be called after the last link to the object is destroyed. Even unset($object) does not guarantee that the destructor is called immediately after unset().

```
$forum = new Forum_class();
$forum->output();
$forumCopy = $forum;
unset($forum); // php doesnt even consider calling the destructor
unset($forumCopy); // now the destructor is going to be called... in some time
```

Comment: Makes sense but what do you mean with... in some time...

If my shutdown function just prints 'cu later', and the next line in my code prints 'my friend'... Isn't it safe to expect 'cu later my friend' as output? (Meaning the destructor method gets called as soon as you really unset the class... Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mean the destructor is going to be called between the moment when the last link is destroyed and the moment when script ends. Developer does not have a way to control or guess the moment when the destructor is called. If you unset several instances, their destructors might be called not in the order they were unset.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should i just skip using the destructor method to do stuff that relies on other classes being active...

Basically, although you can try a hybrid approach:

```
class Foo
{
  protected $resource;

  public function close()
  {
    if ($this->resource)
    {
      $this->resource->foo();
      $this->resource = null;
    }  
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    $this->close();
  }
}
```

This way you can explicitly "close" your resource, but also lazily do it via the destructor just in case.

If the cleanup (the `close()` method) is critical, then I'd change the `__destruct` method to log to a file (e.g., trigger a notice) if it wasn't cleaned up. That way you could easily find and correct those issues.